# How to make a footnote appear only when a solution is displayed?

Tags: footnotes, exam

I'm trying to add footnotes to the solution of an exam I write using the `exam` class.

The following code displays the footnote mark but not the footnote:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,answers]{exam}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    How are you today?
    
    \begin{solution}
    Fine really\footnote{Except for this footnote issue.}.
    \end{solution}
    
    \end{document}
```

This code displays both footmark and footnote, but the footnote persists even without the option `answers` in the `exam` class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}

How are you today?

\begin{solution}
Fine really\footnote{Except for this footnote issue.}.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have everything displayed when option `answers` is on, and nothing when it isn't.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

- Replace `\footnote` with an updated version that issues a `\footnotetext[<num>]{<footnote>}` after the closing of the `solution` environment.
- Some trickery is used to expand the value associated with the footnote to allow multiple footnotes within the same `solution`.

[image]

```
%\documentclass{exam}
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

% Just for this example
\setlength{\textheight}{10\baselineskip}

\usepackage{etextools,etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{%
  \let\oldfootnote\footnote% Store original footnote
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{% Update \footnote
    \oldfootnote{#1}% Original footnote
    \ifprintanswers
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\AfterGroup{\noexpand\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}}\x%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

How are you today?

\begin{solution}
Fine really\footnote{Except for this footnote issue.}.
Or just okay\footnote{No more footnote issues.}.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly.

Comment: Oh, with this solution it turns out that \mathbb{R} is not compiled anymore when inside footnotes, as if the amssymb package was disactivated within footnotes. Do you have a fix for this?

Comment: @Piotr: This happens as a result of the expansion trick. Since I'm loading [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), adding `\robustify\mathbb` in your preamble will avoid expansion of `\mathbb` and make it usable within footnotes. Alternatively, use `\noexpand\mathbb` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Werner.