# Use of \@xfootnote doesn't match its definition

Tags: environments, footnotes, exam

I get an error when compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{exerci}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3}~\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}}
\theoremstyle{exerci}
\newtheorem{exo}[]{Exercice}

\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Solution :}\enspace}

\usepackage{etextools,etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{%
  \let\oldfootnote\footnote% Store original footnote
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{% Update \footnote
    \oldfootnote{#1}% Original footnote
    \ifprintanswers
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\AfterGroup{\noexpand\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}}\x%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exo}[]\label{}
A question.
\begin{solution}
An answer\footnote{I would like to add that
\[\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=x\ln(x)\underset{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} 0.\]} continued.
\end{solution}
\end{exo}

\end{document}
```

The error code is as follows:

```
! Use of \@xfootnote doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a {
\def \@currenvir {equation*}\edef \@currenvline...
l.31 ...\underset{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} 0.\]}
continued.
```

Clearly the `solution` environment one helped me define [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568558/how-to-make-a-footnote-appear-only-when-a-solution-is-displayed) doesn't like math in its footnotes. This is, however, not always the case since *some* short footnotes containing math happen to compile properly.

Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: I don't understand why you make this complicated redefinition, in your other question I would have simply done `\ifprintanswers \makesavenoteenv{solution}\fi`. But doing an \edef over an argument which can contain everything is bound to explode. Beside this: better don't use etextools, it is unmaintained and not always compatible.

Comment: Thanks! It's much simpler indeed and works like a charm (after calling the `footnote` package).